# HTTP code 302 error when requesting URL vie PHP Curl

Tags: php, html, libcurl

I got 302 error message when requesting a url via PHP curl_exec, but got code 200 when do it manually. What could possibly be the difference that makes the result different?

Suppose I have the following code in the server:

```
$url = "http://localhost/circle/my_request/susan?confirm_key=c429d674e36ffe1a4f87fd5a17a0200dcfff0884e8bb3801d2a7d559dcc8d8cd1416295160";
$ch = @curl_init($url);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Circle)");
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
$s = @curl_exec($ch);
$curl_info = @curl_getinfo($ch);
$http_code = $curl_info['http_code'];
```

In this case, $http_code == 302, or the requested URL is redirected. But when I put the URL manually to the browser, it didn't do the redirection, and took me to the correct place.

Do I miss anything? How come those 2 requests result differently?

Thanks in advance

-----------additional info----

Hi I rerun the script with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option set to true, and I got the following output:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 14:36:37 
GMT Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) 
PHP/5.4.12 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12 
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=92t2db5qalq4ajie0ols03hik6; 
path=/; HttpOnly Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate,
post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache X-Account-Management-Status: none 

Location: http://somehost.com/circle Content-Length: 0 

Content-Type: text/html HTTP/1.1 

301 Moved Permanently Date: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 14:36:37 
GMT Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) 

PHP/5.4.12 Location: http://somehost.com/circle/ 

Content-Length: 232 Content-Type: text/html; 
charset=iso-8859-1 HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue,
18 Nov 2014 14:36:37 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64)
PHP/5.4.12 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=hk02sg1327eq78khbka0sf6pk6; 
path=/; HttpOnly Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 
GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, 
post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache X-Account-Management-Status: none 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I'm not sure what it says, but I'm guessing it got redirected to http://somehost.com/circle then to http://somehost.com/circle. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be script use redirect for check cookies or may be for other features.

1. You can see redirect URL in `$s` output. Just insert `echo $s;` to end of your script.
2. Also you can set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and then curl will fllow by redirect in automatic mode.

Comment: @ethereal1m You try connect to script with SESSION. For store session used cookies. In this redirect script set cookie, then redirect to self and check that cookie is installed. For browser there is no problem. You should configure CURL for use cookie.

Comment: are you saying that I should use cookie to figure out the redirection? Also how to connect with SESSION? is it by setting curl_setopt CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION to TRUE and CURLOPT_COOKIE to whatever?

Answer (score 4):

try to add more options

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```